# Can a 2x6 beam span 11ft?

Tags: safety, beam, pergola, span-tables

I need to span a beam 11' between two 6x6 posts to support the rafters for a covered pergola. I was thinking of fastening 3 pieces of 2x6 together to create a stronger piece. Is it possible?

Is there a calculator somewhere for this? I was looking at some tables, but most of them are for decks, which require higher loads than this - 10psf dead load, 5psf live load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Sagulator](http://www.woodbin.com/calcs/sagulator/). Putting in some quick numbers for Ponderosa Pine, I found a single 2x6 on edge to be acceptable for an 11' span holding up to ~1000 pounds total. Laminating 2 or 3 together will be plenty acceptable, and may be overkill, depending on the wood you're using.

Comment: If the load values are right for your local code. This sounds close to me +