# Triple 2x6 beam

Tags: beam

I have Pole barn that has offices built inside and a second floor that is an attic. I am wanting to remove the center wall that is a load bearing wall to open it up. The space is 32’x 40’. I was thinking of using 3 2x6 glued and screwed together. Was wondering how far a part to put the support poles to support the beam?

Comment: I'm no structural engineer, but a 2x6" or 3 isn't going to span 32' or 40' - not by looooong shot! I was going to use 2x8" for my deck joists with a 10' span. Our inspector insisted we go to a 2x10" for that span. If you're going to put posts in with 2x6" beams, you'll probably need a post every 6' (maybe less) to meet load requirements.

Comment: Also not a structural engineer, but I agree with @FreeMan that your posts would need to be closer than you'd probably like. Usually if the height of the beam is a factor, steel I-beam is used instead as these can be fairly short (6-8" tall) with very long spans (20' perhaps) between posts.

Comment: Long story short, contract a local Structural Engineer to look at your building and have him/her design the process for removing a load bearing wall. His career depends on him getting it right, and your life may depend on it. I wouldn't trust strangers on the internet for guesses on this, even though I feel I "know" some of the people here and know they're well intentioned.

Comment: so you're wanting to remove the attic wall that supports the ridge beam?  what is supporting this wall?  are you certain that the wall is not actually a truss?

Comment: From the [related questions](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/100058/can-a-2x6-beam-span-11ft?rq=1) list (over there --->), to give you an idea of a _no load_ span of a 2x6.